# Capture Control + Space keyboard event

Tags: java, java-canvas

I want *leftCanvas* to capture all keyboard events, including *Control + Space*. How can I achieve that since it is triggering the native `InputMethod`?

```
class leftCanvas extends Canvas implements KeyListener {
    leftCanvas() {
        addKeyListener(this);
        enableInputMethods(false);
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.getKeyChar());
        event.consume();
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        event.consume();
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
        event.consume();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have to deal with system global hotkeys, like <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>.

It seems JNI is necessary, and I found the project [jnativehook](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/) which looks really good!